# Unable to edit 'URL'. The style sheet must be part of the project

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have been getting this error in Visual Studio 2012 every time I try type an element and the class attribute (i.e. `<div class="`). It will popup and some times it even crashes Visual Studio if I hit enter too fast.

[image]

Is there anyway to get rid of this error while still getting the list of all the CSS classes?

Comment: I too am facing the same issue in VS 2012 , were you able to identify the reason?

Comment: No, but VS 2013 and VS 2015 don't have the issue.

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same problem and a little search brought me to the following page:

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1586914.aspx?Unable+to+edit+CSS+file+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1586914.aspx?Unable%20to%20edit%20CSS%20file%20)

In a nutshell:  Add a fake parameter to the end of your CDN URL to get rid of your errors. This also makes intellisense work correctly.

Example:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?parameter=1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me too in VS 2012. I wonder why this solution is accepted as an answer, may be old post so :D

Comment: Work also for me with VS2019 community edition. Tks

Answer (score 4):

`Visual Studio` retrieves intellisense from your `css` to tell you which classes are available.
You have a reference to that `css` file but of course don't have edit permission. Looks like a bug to me. Try to remove that reference `css` file and see if problem go away and file a bug.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a solution, but if I'm going to award bounty to anyone, it will be the one person who actually read and understood the question and my issue.

Comment: this is actually very sad. I hope you get a solution, I'm sorry I can't help any further.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bundling? Maybe you could try to use the cdn feature, like this:

```
bundleList.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/24mx/css", "https://cdnurl/bootstrap.css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"
    )
);
```

What this will do is use the cdn in release mode and the local css in debug. So just download that css to have it locally and then it will use the cdn when you publish. Maybe that will help. Ideally you should also use a cdn fallback if it fails:

```
bundleList.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/24mx/css", "https://cdnurl/bootstrap.css"){ CdnFallbackExpression = "javascript expression" }.Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"
    )
);
```

Exactly how to write this expression for a css I haven't really looked into myself.

Comment: That doesn't help. I'm trying to type html and I need the auto complete to remember the 2000 different similarly named classes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if there is any online refernce to css like

```
netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

in your codes. Also please check with a local version of css in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the rel attribute to

```
<link rel="stylesheet nofollow"...>
```

This is a work around. From what I can see the problem seems to be that visual studio is trying to adjust the line endings but does not have write permissions. From comments I've found on the web you need to be careful with this as YUI and some versions of IE may not work properly with the nofollow rel value. Personally, I would remove the nofollow before publishing live. A bit of a hassle, but I think it does answer your question as it does avoid the popup box.

Answer (score -1):

Your web pages need to be either under a Web Site or a Web Application project to be able to edit linked style sheets. Here is what you need to do:

```
1.Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions
2.Check “Always show solution”
3.Right click on the Solution node in the Solution Explorer
4.Choose Add new Web Site or new Web Application project
5.Move your web pages to the new Web Site or Web Application project
```

Now you should be able to edit the linked style sheets.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to edit the stylesheet... That error pops up every time i just type `class="`