# Office JS Stylesheets with VS HTML Editor

Tags: office-js, office-addins, visual-studio-2022

So I'm trying to build an office add in and I opted for Visual Studio thinking that since it has native support for Office JS it would have the ability to add in HTML code formatted for Office JS using the Office UI Fabric.

The problem is that when you try to edit any of the properties in HTML web editor mode on the .html files it pings you with an error saying you don't have permission to edit the CSS file. This is surprising but not unexpected. The file is a remote style sheet you are importing from Office UI Fabric. Not one you made yourself. It's a read only file. However, if you try and edit the HTML manually, there is intelisense built in that will auto complete the class attributes for you from the linked stylesheet.

What I expected to happen was for VS to see the linked CSS file and go "Oh, I have options for these HTML attributes" and just give me a clean drop down menu somewhere to modify the elements in Web Editor based on the external CSS. What happens instead is that it tries to place in normal HTML attributes with no regard for the style sheet.

**The real question I'm driving at is, is there a way to make VS give me attribute options based on premade linked CSS files?** I am admittedly new to VS so I might just be ignorant but several hours of searching on google has yielded very little results. I can't imagine someone hasn't made this functionality if it doesn't already exist and I can't help but feel I'm missing something stupidly obvious. If not, I'm comfortable enough with HTML to muddle through the old fashioned way but it seems silly in this age to have to.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the scenario.  What HTML attributes or values would you expect to be based on the CSS file?

Comment: @Jimmy I am expecting the Web Editor view to provide information on available options for class attributes specifically for Microsoft Office formatting using Office UI Fabric. The options are there in the Properties window on the right but as an example if I try to edit the color of text it wants to apply a font color CSS attribute to all files it can find. I would settle for an option that would just let Web Editor ignore the Fabric CSS file. I looked into that issue specifically and found a bunch of work arounds like adding fake parameters to the <link> tags href attribute.

Comment: I'm fine with a work around, but none of them worked and it felt more like a band aid than an actual solution anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498539/unable-to-edit-url-the-style-sheet-must-be-part-of-the-project provides a screenshot of a similar error and suggestions on solutions but they do not work.